# Connect to a SLOT in Qt

Tags: qt

I have a main window, where is a button, which creates a new window, if pressed. So it works fine, my problem is that I have an another button on the second window. I would like to connect it to a slot, but I always got an error

> No such slot dbManager::addQuestions(QString(question->text()))

This is where I want to connect

```
void WindowManager::addQuestionDialog(){
...
    question = new QLineEdit();
    QObject::connect(validBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()), &db, SLOT(addQuestions(QString(question->text()))));
...
}
```

And this is where I want to conenct (cpp):

```
bool dbManager::addQuestions(QString& a){
    qDebug()<<"Connection";
    return true ;
}
```

.h
public slots:

```
   bool addQuestions(QString& a);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the way you're trying to connect:

```
QObject::connect(validBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()), &db,
                 SLOT(addQuestions(QString(question->text()))));
```

QObject::connect() tries to set up a connection, it doesn't actually pass any arguments. So:

```
SLOT(addQuestions(QString(question->text())))
```

is ill formed because you're trying to pass question->text() as an argument. You can't do that. If you want the slot to receive an argument, it's the signal that should pass it. So you need a signal with a QString argument.

There's multiple ways to solve this. The easiest would be to create a new slot which doesn't take any arguments and which calls addQuestions(). For example:

```
void WindowManager::onValidBtnClick()
{
    question = new QLineEdit();
    db.addQuestions(question->text()));
}
```

And you connect to that:

```
void WindowManager::addQuestionDialog()
{
    // ...
    connect(validBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(onValidBtnClick()));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How could I create a signal, which works like the clicked() and pass the argument?

Comment: @erbal You can create a new slot that calls addQuestions(). Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you! :)
Btw, I don't really understand why can't I pass a QString like this: QString(question->text()). SHouldn't it pass the question->text() as a string?

Comment: @erbal Do you mean in your original code? As already mentioned, connect() doesn't pass anything. You're just writing down the signature of the slot there. `question->text()` is not part of the function signature of addQuestions().

Comment: Ohh, Okay, sorry, you've mentioned connect doesn't pass anything.

Comment: @erbal Note that even *If* the clicked() signal actually had a QString argument, then you still couldn't pass anything at the connect() call. It would then look like this: `connect(validBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(QString)), &db, SLOT(addQuestions(QString)))`. The actual data for the argument would then be passed when you actually emit the signal: `emit clicked(someString)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a slot should always return void. Also do you have the Q_OBJECT macro in your class with the slot and is it public. Like this:

```
class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int m_value;
public:
    int value() const { return m_value; }
public slots:
    void setValue(int value);
```

Comment: There is no requirement for slots to return void. They can be called like normal functions too. For example: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#close Furthermore, you can connect to private slots just fine. You just can't call them directly without a signal/slot connection.

Comment: Yes, I use the Q_OBJECT macro.

Answer (score 0):

A signal's signature and the slot's signature must be matched to connect them properly. 
A useful blog entry for debugging signals and slots: http://samdutton.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/debugging-signals-and-slots-in-qt/

[From the documentation:](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html)

```
 The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving slot. (In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it receives because it can ignore extra arguments.) Since the signatures are compatible, the compiler can help us detect type mismatches.
```

Also please use the new connection syntax. That way you can catch some mistakes at compile time.